# python trick needed to convert dictionary of functions into dictionary of results

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently blank on how to do this in an effective way.I thought about using objects but I don't see how they could help in this case. Any ideas?

```
from random import choice
from copy import deepcopy


def main():

    def rand_int():
        return choice(['yes', 'no'])

    # any nesting, functions possible
    spec = {
        'answer': rand_int,
        'next': {'answer': rand_int},
        'the_answer': 42
    }

    #### looking for elegant (automatic) way to do this
    result = deepcopy(spec)
    result['answer'] = result['answer']()
    result['next']['answer'] = result['next']['answer']()
    #### until here

    # result2 = ...

    print 'result: %s' % result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

please do not tell me to use xsd!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with one line in a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY):

```
{key: function() for key, function in mydictionary.items()}
```

Of course, this will throw errors when a value isn't a function, so if that is a possibility, we can simply add a check with [the `callable()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable):

```
{key: (function() if callable(function) else function) for key, function in mydictionary.items()}
```

We then need to deal with the fact that your answer needs to be recursive, this makes it a little more complex, but not too hard to fix:

```
def call_all_callables_in_dict(mapping):
    if hasattr(mapping, "items"):
        return {key: call_all_callables_in_dict(value) for key, value in mapping.items()}
    elif callable(mapping):
        return mapping()
    else:
        return mapping
```

Note that if you have objects with an `items` attribute or method you wish to store in a `dict` this function will be run on, this could cause problems. I would recommend changing the name of that attribute or method, or replacing the check with `isinstance(dict)`.

I would also like to note that for misleading function names `rand_int` that returns a string of `'yes'` or `'no'` is probably about as bad as it gets. Generally you want `True`/`False` in those situations as well.

As noted in the comments, pre-Python 2.7, you may not have dictionary comprehensions. To get around this, `dict()` will take a generator of tuples, so you can replace a dict comprehension like so:

```
{x: y for x, y in something.items()}
```

With:

```
dict((x, y) for x, y in something.items())
```

---

So, in full:

```
from random import choice

def rand_int():
        return choice(['yes', 'no'])

spec = {
    'answer': rand_int,
    'next': {'answer': rand_int},
    'the_answer': 42
}

def call_all_callables_in_dict(mapping):
    if hasattr(mapping, "items"):
        return {key: call_all_callables_in_dict(value) for key, value in mapping.items()}
    elif callable(mapping):
        return mapping()
    else:
        return mapping

print(call_all_callables_in_dict(spec))
```

Gives us:

```
{'answer': 'no', 'the_answer': 42, 'next': {'answer': 'yes'}}
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker I realised that as I was posting, updating with answers for both.

Comment: Note that dict comprehensions work in Python 2.7+. Also the syntax is with a colon: `{key: value for key, value in dict.items()}`

Comment: @EmilIvanov Indeed, if you are in a previous version, it's a trivial replacement to a generator expression of tuples and `dict()`, e.g.: `{x: y for ...}` turns into `dict((x, y) for ...)`. And don't know how I derped to not put the colon there. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: This is a great solution to my problem. Thanks so much!